# How to prevent toad disconnecting its session after some time?

Tags: oracle, toad

I am using toad for oracle client.

In which the session disconnects after some time. 
How to make it enabled at all time.

Comment: @PatrickHofman "Connection alive" means we have change the settings or we have constantly use the application

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the [Dell website](https://support.software.dell.com/toad-for-oracle/kb/49507):

> Keeping database connections alive is generally not recommended
>
> ...
>
> If you would still like to force connectivity at all times, you can do so by doing one of the following two suggestions.
>
> A)
>
> Turn ON the DBMS Output (Polling) in Toad, which is similar to Toad pinging the database. Go to the Editor Window | DBMS Output Tab (lower half of the Editor window) | click on the "Turn Output On" red icon | then the icon will turn green.
>
> NOTE:  Starting Toad version 12.1, it’s little different.  Also ensure the “Interval Polling” button or icon is 'depressed' as that is the one that sends the polling at every i.e. 5 seconds. You can set this to 60 seconds, which is the max.
>
> B)
>
> Start Database | Monitor | Session Browser, which has an auto refresh feature, which should cause some activities to occur on the database.
>
> NOTE: The Session Browser feature requires DBA privileges.

Answer (score 3):

There is no straightforward way. One way to achieve this is to use the "Test connection(Reconnect)" option with a shortcut command.

1. Go to Session ---> Test Connections(Reconnect) and press enter.
2. You can map the above-mentioned command to an easy key combination so that it 
   will be available for you whenever you get the disconnected error.
3. To map the shortcuts, Go to

View ---> Toad Options ---> Select "Shortcuts" in the available options.
Find the TestConnections(Reconnect) command and assign new shortcuts keys you wanted.

Comment: It will not prevent, but of course it helps for easy recovery

Answer (score 1):

I also encounterd this problem and found a solution.
At Startup of Toad the Session Browser also has to be open all the time to keep the connection Alive.
You can do this automatically by setting the Auto Open checkbox on.
You do this in menu View/Toad Options/Windows and then to scroll down and find the Session browser and turn the Auto open checkbox on.
☺

Answer (score 0):

You can follow as the below picture, step by step:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Review information on "[Dead connection Detection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/oraclenetdcd-2179641.pdf)" (DCD)
EXCERPT:  "A less common usage scenario for DCD is to keep database connections alive when an external firewall timeout is configured to terminate idle connections."

This is especially noticeable with JDBC connections in environments with strict firewalls.

[Using JDBC with Firewalls](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxtblsh.htm#JJDBC28984)
and the next section: Frequent Abrupt Disconnection from Server EXCERPT: "If the network is not reliable, then it is difficult for a client to detect the frequent disconnections when the server is abruptly disconnected."

Example:  Automic Applications Manager

1a.  Add the following to the sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME=10 # some number less than the firewall
```

1b.  Reload the listener.

```
lsnrctl reload listener
```

2. Add the following to the client tnsnames.ora connection string

   (ENABLE=BROKEN) # immediately after: (DESCRIPTION=